# How do I disable mouse support in mcedit when it is called via F4 from within mc?

Tags: mc

I have a problem with Midnight Commander that I am finding exceptionally annoying.  I hope that you can provide some relief to me.

I want to use Midnight Commander without mouse support, with mouse actions invoking my X terminal emulator program's functionality rather than being passed through to Midnight Commander.  So I invoke Midnight Commander with the command-line option that does that, via an alias

```
alias mc='mc -d'
```

This works all well and good … until I press <kbd>F4</kbd> to edit a file.  Because (I think) I am using the so-called *internal* editor, this brings up `mcedit`, to which all of my mouse actions are passed because the mouse is enabled in it.

I know that the `-d` option works when I manually invoke the editor with `mcedit -d` and a file.  How do I get the same when `mc` invokes the editor with <kbd>F4</kbd>?

Midnight Commander has this option of not using the mouse for both its `mc` and `mcedit` programs and I want to know how to turn it on throughout the whole of Midnight Commander, including when invoking its supposedly *internal* editor (that surely, if it *were* internal, should be respecting the `-d` option that I gave to `mc`).

Latter Edit: I have shell variables EDITOR and VISUAL set to '/usr/bin/mcedit', now I just changed them to `/usr/bin/mcedit -d` ... still don't work, then I tried to set a path with higher priority where I put a script called mcedit that call `/usr/bin/mcedit -d $*` (verified that is first with `which mcedit`) ... still same problem

Comment: Can't reproduce this with mc 4.8.21.

Comment: I cannot get to that mc version, I just tried on Mint 18.3, Mint 19 (which has the same versions with latest Ubuntu - 18.04), also on latest Knoppix, maximum mc version I got was 4.8.19, and all got the same problem in my above question, so, what is your Linux distro ?

Comment: Debian buster (testing). https://packages.debian.org/buster/mc

Comment: @IporSircer what can't you reproduce exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solve it with making `mcedit` alias bash file:

1. Rename `/usr/bin/mcedit` to `/usr/bin/mcedit_orig`
2. And add new bash script file `/usr/bin/mcedit` with content:

```
!/bin/bash

mcedit_orig -d "$@"
```

3. Change `/usr/bin/mcedit` file chmod to 755 using this command:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/mcedit
```

mc will work as you will run it, and mcedit will always run with `-d` parameter